# Doctrine2 get populated types for ManyToMany relation?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm unsure how to get all hotel types that have "at least one" hotel? As the relation is ManyToMany.

So with queryBuilder, I assumed I can do something like:

```
$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();

$qb->select('t')
     ->from(HotelType::class, 't', 't.id')
     ->join('t.hotels', 'm');
```

But this doesn't seem to work? I'm not sure what I must do. Here are my two entities:

HotelType entity :

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * HotelType
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="hotel_type")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class HotelType
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Hotel", cascade={"persist"}, mappedBy="mType")
     */
    private $hotels;
}
```

Hotel entity :

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Hotel
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="hotel")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Application\Repository\HotelRepository")
 */
class Hotel
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="HotelType", inversedBy="hotels", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="hotel_hoteltype",
     * joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="hotel_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     * inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="hoteltype_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    private $mType;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->mType = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getMType()
    {
        return $this->mType;
    }

    public function addMType($mtype)
    {
        if (!$this->mType->contains($mtype) && is_object($mtype)) {
            $this->mType->add($mtype);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeMType($mtype)
    {

        if ($this->mType->contains($mtype) && is_object($mtype)) {
            $this->mType->removeElement($mtype);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function clearMType()
    {
        $this->mType->clear();

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks good to me. Is there any error? And are you sure to not forgot `->getQuery()->getResult()`? Do your Entities have a namespace?

Comment: `..doesn't seem to work` is it throwing an error? Returning nothing? Do queries on other entities work?

Comment: Hmm it seems to have been a problem elsewhere, all working now (it was giving 0 results when it should have given more... now it works)